# Android- custom imageButton return view without extra fields

Tags: android, imagebutton

in my android application i built a custom imageButton with extra field:

```
public class MyImageButton extends ImageButton {

private String _absolutePath;

public MyImageButton(Context context, String absolutePath) { 
    super(context);
    this.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    this.set_absolutePath(absolutePath);
}
```

...}

(I added all the constructors needed, it's compiled well).

The XML for this imageButton is:

```
        <my.package.MyImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="imageButtonPressed" />
```

The problem is when click on the ImageButton, the method:

```
public void imageButtonPressed(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(this, ((MyImageButton)view).get_absolutePath(), 1).show();

}
```

**The _absolutePath field in the MyImageButton is null.**
i assume that the problem is the conversion (casting) and in the native method which call by the original view, and i can't figure out how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this topic http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr. You need to define custom attribute and then you can specify the custom value in xml file. Or you can use your code, but it won't work with xml.

Comment: Do u have any idea how to get the absolute URL from ImageButton when pressed @andrew_pako ?